# Pass from tiddlywiki list to python list

Tags: python, arrays, string, python-3.x

Tiddlywiki uses [internally](https://github.com/Jermolene/TiddlyWiki5/issues/3081) a space-separated tags for making a list of tags. But it uses `[[` and `]]` to limit multi-word tags.
That is, a list of `foo`, `ram doo`, `bar` and `very cool` becomes in tiddlywiki a string like that:

```
"foo [[ram doo]] bar [[very cool]]"
```

How can I transform that into python list that look like:

```
['foo', 'ram doo', 'bar', 'very cool']
```

`"foo [[ram doo]] bar".split()` does not work for me..

Comment: [You were given the link](https://github.com/Jermolene/TiddlyWiki5/issues/3081#issuecomment-355952824) to the stringifying function and the function right below it does the parsing, no? Just translate that to Python?

Comment: It's better to ask and someone gets helped with my question and your answers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With regex:

```
import re
a = "foo [[ram doo]] bar [[very cool]] something else"
pattern = re.compile(r'\[\[[^\]]+\]\]|[^\[\] ]+')
print([i.strip(' []') for i in pattern.findall(a)])
```

Prints `['foo', 'ram doo', 'bar', 'very cool', 'something', 'else']`

Regex basically "tokenizes" the string (borders are either `[[..]]` or space, in that order), the list comprehension then removes the brackets from the tokens.

Answer (score 3):

A simple regular expression works:

```
>>> import re
>>> [x.strip() for x in re.split('\[\[|\]\]',  "foo [[ram doo]] bar [[very cool]]") if x]
['foo', 'ram doo', 'bar', 'very cool']
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Adjusted accordingly.

Comment: but now some variables are having spaces inside

Comment: Still doesn't split `"foo bar"`.

Answer (score 1):

This will work fine. Two line code, without Regular expression:

```
>>> s =  "foo [[ram doo]] bar [[very cool]]"
>>> [x.strip() for x in " ".join(s.replace('[[','*').replace(']]','*').split("*")).split(" ") if x]
['foo', 'ram', 'doo', 'bar', 'very', 'cool']
```

Comment: Why would you introduce an arbitrary character like *, maybe * is part of the tag, and this would fail.

Comment: @Kuro Thanks for pointing out. I have edited the code accordingly :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the following way, without using `re`

Obviously using `re` would be more efficient, this answer only to demonstrate that you can do this with `split()`

[EDITED based on comment]

```
my_string = "foo [[ram doo]] bar [[very cool]]"

# also works for the following strings
#my_string = "foo [[ram doo]] bar [[very cool]] something else"
#my_string = "something else"
#my_string = "foo bar [[ram doo]]" ##<-- this is the border case
#my_string = "[[ram doo]] foo bar"
#my_string = "foo [[ram doo]] bar "

# set "splitting string"
s1 = ']]'
s2 = '[['
if my_string[-2::] == ']]' and my_string.count(']]') == 1:
    # reverse splitting string for border case
    s1 = '[['
    s2 = ']]'

# split on s1 only if s1 in string
my_list1 = [a if s1 in my_string else my_string for a in my_string.split(s1)]

# split each element on s2 or space
my_list2 = [x.split(s2) if s2 in x else x.split(' ') for x in my_list1]

# flatten lists in lists, and strip spaces
my_list3 = [a.strip(' ') for b in my_list2 for a in (b if isinstance(b, list) else [b])]

# get rid of empties
my_list4 = [a for a in my_list3 if a != '']
print(my_list4)
# will output
# ['foo', 'ram doo', 'bar', 'very cool']
```

so, the conclusion is to use `re`

Comment: Still fails for example `"foo bar [[ram doo]]"`.

Comment: @StefanPochmann answer updated, but it is getting rediculous now, so you can do it without `re`, but you really should not use it (it being my answer). Answer provided only to proof you can... ah well... back to my day job, where I would use `re` in such situation. Had to do an `if` for the border case. Although I could have included this in the comprehension it would have made it unreadable